# How to create a complex Json structure manually in android without using API?

Tags: java, android, json, arraylist

I would like to create a Json structure manually using JsonObject and JsonArrays like the below:

```
{
 "data":[
         {
          "company_name":"xyz",
          "Amount":"$2000",
          "Duplicate_amount":"$500"
         },
         {
          "company_name":"abc",
          "Amount":"$5000"
         },
         {
          "company_name":"zzz",
          "Amount":"$2500",
          "Duplicate_amount":"$1000"
         }
      ]
}
```

The Json above is to be generated based on a checking done on an **Arraylist**. For example: **Arraylist [xyz,abc,zzz,xyz,hhh,zzz]**. Now I want to check, if the arraylist contains duplicate elements i.e  here "xyz" and "zzz" then in the Json structure, the **Duplicate_amount** Json object to be added in the Json. Else if no duplicate present then only "company_name" and  "amount" to be formed. The whole json format to be formed in this way.

How to do it? I have the logic for finding duplicate elements. But I cannot seem to find the logic for forming the above json based on the checking.

Thank you

***Updates***

So far I have tried this with checking. But the below code doesn't work and is not forming the appropriate json. What is the solution ?:

```
    JSONObject root_jsonObj = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray jsonArr = new JSONArray();
    JSONObject sub_jsonobj= new JSONObject();
    Object[] st = AppData.customer_arr.toArray();
    for (Object s : st) {

     //The if-else is the duplicate checking part here
        if (AppData.customer_arr.indexOf(s) != AppData.customer_arr.lastIndexOf(s)) {

            try {
                sub_jsonobj.put("name",AppData.customer_arr.get(counter));
                sub_jsonobj.put("dup_amount",AppData.amt_arr.get(counter));

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else{
            try {
                sub_jsonobj.put("name",AppData.customer_arr.get(counter));
                sub_jsonobj.put("amount",AppData.amt_arr.get(counter));

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        jsonArr.put(sub_jsonobj);
        counter++;
    }
    try {
        root_jsonObj.put("data", jsonArr);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: convert them into pojo and then compare them using equals method . Just include equals method in your POJO.

Comment: Can you give an example? It would be helpful

Answer (score 2):

You can use this one.

```
JSONObject obj1 = new JSONObject();
try {
    obj1.put("company_name", "xyz");
    obj1.put("Amount", "$2000");
    obj1.put("Duplicate_amount", "$500");

} catch (JSONException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

JSONObject obj2 = new JSONObject();
try {
    obj2.put("company_name", "xyz");
    obj2.put("Amount", "$2000");


} catch (JSONException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}


JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray();

jsonArray.put(obj1);
jsonArray.put(obj2);

JSONObject dataObj = new JSONObject();
    dataObj.put("Data", jsonArray);



String jsonStr = dataObj.toString();

    System.out.println("jsonString: "+jsonStr);
```

Comment: I am sorry but it doesnot solve my question. I want  to form the whole Json structure based on the duplicate checking if it contains duplicate or not in an arraylist. how to solve that?

Comment: you can parse the json to string than you can make your duplicate search.